# On mouseover/mouseout of javascript vs hover of css where on hover on div tag some other element get changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coding-style

I have a `div` element and I want to show an image just below it when the user hovers over the `div`. Through Javascript can do this with the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events but I want to do this using `CSS`.

So how can I do it using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS :after selectors for this effect.

```
#myDIV:hover:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

from there you can style it as a regular element with your image as the background, or edit the content field to your liking. This will insert a pseudo element when you hover over #myDIV.
If you need support for older browsers, you can look in to using your javascript code as a fallback, and use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect browser capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [sibling selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/combinators) like `+` or `~`: http://jsbin.com/uvepiq/1/edit

They will allow you to do a `:hover` check on one element and apply styles to a following sibling element. So the image's normal style will be hidden with `display: none`, and then when its preceding sibling is hovered, you can style it as `display: block` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS:

```
<div class="outer">
    Texty Texterson...
    <div><img src="http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi" /></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.outer div{
    display: none;
}

.outer:hover div{
    display: block;
}
```

But I will say doing this with jQuery/javascript enables you to do some nice effects like fade, etc.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.outer').hover(
    function () { 
        $(this).find('div').fadeIn();
    }, 
    function () { 
        $(this).find('div').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: What @KyleSomogyi said if using CSS :after. If using jquery use .next('img') or whatever your element is.